# How to compute vector of force to apply to my physics body in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, swift, math

I'd like to move my object from one point to another, but I don't want to use a 'move' action.

So I'll apply a force or an impulse, I don't know which one I should use and I don't know how to compute the needed vector force.

Comment: It will probably depend on whether the physics body is under player control or not.  If it's not then it will be fairly difficult to get the body to the right place without lots of feedback/adjustment and it's not normally how it's done. Have you checked [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/making_physics_bodies_move)?

Comment: thanks, I'll check that.